# dhclient overwriting resolv.conf

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp

I'm setting up virtual dev environments and I want the hostname.domain to be something specific, eg- "barney.local".  However my `/etc/resolv.conf` file keeps getting nuked because i'm using DHCP.  I placed this into my `dhclient.conf`:

```
supersede domain-name "localhost"
supersede host-name "barney"
```

.. but it didn't help. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.  How can I still use DHCP but configure that virtual environment to see itself as barney.local?

fyi i'm running debian squeeze

Answer (score 0):

If you are running debian squeeze, you have an automated option when you install bind9 from repository to resolve with bind instead of using the DNS provided by DHCP.

Then you can add you own TLD (like .local) in bind to resolve them.

You'll find the configuration of dhclient in /etc/dhcp3/ . But are you sure that the problem is comming from the resolv configuration and not from your DNS server ?

nslookup can help you to figure out that. Without more informations, I cannot know where the problem comes from, so cannot be more specific than pointing you some directions.